# Can not load property file in spring-context.xml. Property file Path is given as a placeholder in dev.properties

Tags: spring, properties, property-placeholder

> I am loading property file in spring-context.xml and i am giving
>   external property file location in
>   **${spring.profiles.active}.properties** which is in classpath and using the location as a placholder in **spring-context.xml**. My **spring-context.xml** is:

```
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="locations" ref="propertyConfigurerFiles" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurerFiles" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
    <list>
    <value>/WEB-INF/properties/common.properties</value>

    <!--In Developemnet Enviroenment it will be dev.properties-->
    <value>/WEB-INF/properties/${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value> 

    <!--External Property File Location as a Placeholder-->
    <value>${app.config.batch.location}</value>

    </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

**And my dev.properties is:**

```
    app.config.batch.location=E:/project/properties/config.properties
```

> My problem is that is **${app.config.batch.location}** placeholder is not
>   resolved in spring-context.xml and its trying to load file
>   **${app.config.batch.location}** in place of
>   **E:/project/properties/config.properties**.

I hope I explained the problem well. Please help!

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create bean of class PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer.
Not just some ArrayList bean. Why do you think you need this ArrayList bean?

Comment: Hi @Юрий Плевако I needed ArrayList bean for reference.I modified my question and posted my complete spring-context.xml.

Comment: So you need to have PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer to be instantiated when you are creating your ArrayList bean, because you use placeholders in your ArrayList bean configuration, and you don't have it. Possible way is to have some placeholders which are resolved by your build system while it is processing resources

Comment: Yeah.I know that But I am not able to find a way to achieve it. If you can suggest something it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: E.g. with gradle this would be something like this:
`processResources {
        filesMatching('*.properties') {
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [MYTOKEN: 'mytokenvalue'])
        }
    } `
And in properties file you wanna add `@MYTOKEN@` placeholder

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using spring profiles, instead of messing with initialization time property value binding what you can do is ...
1) read the property file(profile's)
    /WEB-INF/properties/${spring.profiles.active}.properties 
2) create a java class that can read these property values. (don't forget to use spring profiles interfacing class)
3) as you are trying to read a property file whose location is embedded in property file(step-1), object created at step-2 will give value for key `<value>${app.config.batch.location}</value>`
now you can load this property file using available file reader class.
4) create `Properties` object and access the values in it.

Note:: if any of your bean initialization depends on key-value read at step-4, do initialization manually or create your ***custom class(servlet) that get loaded before any other class (even spring's DispactherServlet).